# Call blazor component function based on some condition

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have two buttons ***"User Info"*** and ***"Transactions"***. Based on the button click, i am maintaining the state using `StateContainer`. If user clicked on the ***"User Info"***, i will set `StateContainer.SelectedButton = "User"`, if clicked on the ***"Transactions"***, i will set `StateContainer.SelectedButton = "Transactions"` .

Based on this `StateContainer.SelectedButton` value, I am showing different components in popup as below:

```
<div class="popup">
    <div class="popup-overlay">
        @if (StateContainer.SelectedButton== "User")
        {
            <UserDetails></UserDetails>
        }
        else if (StateContainer.SelectedButton== "Transactions")
        {
              <Transactions></Transactions>
        }

    </div>
</div>
```

And this popup is already added to the main index page.

**UserDetails** component :

```
<div>
User Details
</div>
@code {
protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    try
    {
        StateContainer.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
        GetUserDetails();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return base.OnInitializedAsync();
}
private async Task GetUserDetails()
{
    //Call to get user details
}
}
```

Since the popup is already included in the index page, seems the `GetUserDetails()` function is getting called only once. if i click on the button multiple times, this function is not getting called. How can i achieve that?

Comment: In the Index page, use @ref on User Details component to capture component reference. Then you can make the method public and call it by accessing the reference

Comment: maybe it was called the thing it us not triggering. Try to console that if that works or if you have a component try to make `Eventcallback`

Comment: Are you using .net8?

Comment: You've only provided the code for half the story.  You don't show the buttons, the state container or how you show or hide the popup div.  If you simply hide and show `<UserDetails>`  then you are not creating a new `UserDetails` each time, just reusing the existing one in the render tree.   If popup is a modal dialog, why don't you use one of the Blazor Modal dialogs that already exist [for free]?

Comment: @QiangFu yes .net8